# Finding the equivalent Thevenin generator

Tags: thevenin

I have 2 circuits of which I'm supposed to find the Thevenin's generator equivalent.

I solved the first one (hopefully correctly), but am unsure how to solve the second one.

The result of the first one is: `TE = 3.75 V` *(`TE` being the Thevenin equivalent of the original `E`).*

[image: G1]

If we add `R4` (parallel with `R3`), I get lost.

---

For the first circuit, I used the formula `TE = (E * R3) / (R1 + R3)`

How would I go about solving the second circuit?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is wrong. Notice that the right side of an R3 resistor is not connected. Hence no current can flow via R3. No current means no voltage drop across R3.

Comment: And Vth = TE = 3V for both circuits. But Rth will be different. Rth1 = 250R and Rth2 = 300R

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you calculated `TE` (`Vth`) for the circuits so that it's `3V`?

Comment: Have you been taught that the open circuit voltage between A and B is the Thevenin equivalent voltage?

Comment: Yes, I do know that Crustacean. I got some values swapped by my bad, and I got the correct result in the end (`3V`).